React Native fixed footer with KeyboardAwareScrollView
I'm trying to implement a screen that have a fixed bottom buttons with KeyboardAwareScrollView.
The problems that I have is when I put my buttons outside of the KeyboardAwareScrollView for fixed, when the keyboard shown, it will also push the buttons above the keyboard instead of hide it as KeyboardAwareScrollView should do ( as when I put it inside the KeyboardAwareScrollView). This only occurs in android (I'm using adjustResize).
https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view
